# One-sided limit with factorial/Gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, gamma-function

I was wondering if the following limit could be evaluated:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left|\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(-x)}\right|$$

I wondered if we could take the limit as $x$ approached $-1$ and compare the left and right side.  I'm not even sure if this can be solved, and my knowledge on limits says it probably can't be solved.

But if you have an answer, you are welcome to give it a try.

Comment: Factorial is a discrete function so I don't know what you mean with that. What you definition of $x!$ when $x$ is not a non-negative integer ?

Comment: @GiovanniResta Oh yeah, I'll use the gamma function.  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Gamma$ has a simple pole at $z = 0$, i.e. $\Gamma(z) = c/z + g(z)$ where $g$ is analytic near zero (and $c = 1$), one obtains
$$
\frac{\Gamma(z)}{\Gamma(-z)} = \frac{c + zg(z)}{-c + zg(-z)}
$$
and thus the limit is 1. More generally, if $f$ has a pole of order $k$ at $z = 0$, then 
$$
\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z)}{f(-z)} = (-1)^k \, .
$$
This is in other words not restricted to the Gamma function.